# Evenly arrange (3) rows of (5) text inputs with Bootstrap3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My goal is to arrange 3 rows of 5 text inputs in Bootstrap's column. Each text input should has 5 chars maximum width (`size` attribute of a text input).

Here is what I have for now. Please, also check the full page view of the snippet.

```css
.inputs {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.stuff {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 stuff"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 inputs">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="a" class="control-label">A</label>
                    <input type="text" value="1" class="form-control" id="a" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="b" class="control-label">B</label>
                    <input type="text" value="2" class="form-control" id="b" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="c" class="control-label">C</label>
                    <input type="text" value="3" class="form-control" id="c" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="d" class="control-label">D</label>
                    <input type="text" value="4" class="form-control" id="d" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <label for="e" class="control-label">E</label>
                    <input type="text" value="5" class="form-control" id="e" size="5" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I'm facing 2 main problems:

1. inputs are not evenly arranged;
2. their width is 100% to parent container, so `size` attribute values is ignored;

What's the best way to solve that task?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using col-xs-2 and col-md-2 create a custom css class with a width of 20% and the rest of the default styles that are usually on a col-*

Comment: thanks, it's the good solution. do you think it's possible to do that via bootstrap3's grid system?

Comment: Not out of the box, you'll have to use a little custom CSS to get 5 even columns without any offsets.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using bootstrap's built in push class. You can tweak the smaller col sizes on my example as needed. But I believe by setting more column sizes and push, this is what you wanted to achieve.

```css
.inputs {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.stuff {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 stuff"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 inputs">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-1 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="a" class="control-label">A</label>
                    <input type="text" value="1" class="form-control" id="a" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-1 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="b" class="control-label">B</label>
                    <input type="text" value="2" class="form-control" id="b" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-1 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="c" class="control-label">C</label>
                    <input type="text" value="3" class="form-control" id="c" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-1 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="d" class="control-label">D</label>
                    <input type="text" value="4" class="form-control" id="d" size="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-1 col-lg-2">
                    <label for="e" class="control-label">E</label>
                    <input type="text" value="5" class="form-control" id="e" size="5" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```